# split a column to two columns using r

Tags: r

I want to split V2 column to two columns by ')*('

```
V1                                  V2
r1      (Direct)*(Mary*(Sewnf 45*S-a))
r2 (Ax 70a12*Qunion)*(Kin - 32431*Tip)
r3           (PAN*Q-23)*(BE 05/514/10)
```

then I can see below.

```
V1                V2                          V3
r1           (Direct        Mary*(Sewnf 45*S-a))
r2  (Ax 70a12*Qunion            Kin - 32431*Tip)
r3         (PAN*Q-23               BE 05/514/10)
```

Here is something I have tried, but apparently it does not get my goal.

```
library(stringr)
str_split_fixed(as.character(data$V2), '\\)*(', 2)
str_split_fixed(as.character(data$V2), '\\)*\\(', 2)
```

and also trying.

```
strsplit(as.character(data$V2), '\\)*(')
```

How can I revise my script?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can do this with `separate` by specifying the `sep` to match a `)` followed by a `*` and a `(` (these are metacharacters i.e. `()` can be used for capturing as a group while `*` implies 0 or more characters, so it needs to be escaped (`\\`) to parse the literal character.  With `extra=merge`,  it splits only at the first instance of this match and others are merged into the second column i.e. 'V3'

```
library(tidyr)
separate(df1, V2, into = c("V2", "V3"), "\\)\\*\\(", extra = "merge")
#  V1               V2                   V3
#1 r1          (Direct Mary*(Sewnf 45*S-a))
#2 r2 (Ax 70a12*Qunion     Kin - 32431*Tip)
#3 r3        (PAN*Q-23        BE 05/514/10)
```

---

In the OP's code, all the metacharacters were not escaped

Answer (score 4):

```
library(stringr)
data[,c("V2","V3")] <- str_split_fixed(as.character(data$V2), ")*(", 2)
```

This should work!